# Is synchronized being used right in this code?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, synchronized

I want to know if I understand correctly how to use **synchronized** I will write down some **pseudo code**, which mimics what I am trying to do.

```js
public MyApp extends Application {

    public Object mLock = new Object();

    private final ArrayList<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getMyList(){
        return MyList;
    }
}


private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
        final ArrayList<String> BgList = MyApp.getMyList();
        synchronized (mLock) {
            while(somefinishcondition) {
                try {
                    // Get some stuff from the web
                    BgList.add(newstuff);
                    mLock.notifyAll();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

        final ArrayList<String> FgList = MyApp.getMyList();

        synchronized (mLock) {
            while(somecondition) {
                mLock.wait();
                if(FgList.size()>lastSize) {
                    n = FgList.size();
                    for(i=lastSize+1; i<=n ; i++){
                        Display(Fglist.get(i));
                    }
                    lastSize = n;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here is what **I think** I am doing: I am running a data gathering task in the background, putting the data in a global list. Each time I have new data I notify the DisplayActivity, which goes and displays all new data since the last time.
The AsyncTask locks the data until new data arrives. The DisplayActivity waits on the lock until notified to proceed and display.
Is this right? Is this the usual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this way you can block the UI thread in `onCreate` and you will get Application Not Responding error.

Instead, whenever you have some new data, collect the data in `doInBackground()` then call `updateProgress()` in `doInBackground()`. This will result in `AsyncTask.onProgress()` call from the UI thread. In `onProgress()` do whatever you need with the new data.

Comment: But AsyncTask.onProgress cannot, or does too?, interact with the user. What if I run the display synchronized block from a runnable thread, so it does not block the activity?

Comment: AsyncTask.onProgress is executed on the UI thread. The idea is you do background task in doInBackground so you don't block the UI thread but you process the results (e.g. display the results) in onProgress and onPostExecute on UI Thread.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I would not want to deviate from my original question, which is: Is **synchronized** used as it is meant to? Does wait() sits and wait until some other thread notifies? Or is there some other purpose in those functions?

Comment: I would say your code looks unusual in regards to how you use synchronized and AsyncTask. However, that's maybe how you meant it to.